# Import csv file into existing access table using VBA

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access

Hi i have a quick question what is the VBA code that will allow me to import a CSV file into a existing table in Access 2010 with its own field names?

Thanks

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835958.aspx

Answer (score 4):

this should work

```
DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acLinkDelim, TableName:="tblImport", _
        FileName:="C:\MyData.csv", HasFieldNames:=true
```

Comment: np, if you could 'accept' my answer, that'd be nice :)

Comment: Because you use `acLinkDelim` it only _links_ the file to Access, it does not _import_ the data. You need to use `acImportdelim`